# How to auto-update a SQL table when a change is made in another table?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have an Events Management System database with some entities. Two of them are Events and Tickets. In Events, I have maxTickets which holds the maximum number of tickets for an event. My problem is that how do I add those number of "maxTickets" for a particular event in the Tickets table? I have made the EventID as a foreign key to the Tickets table.

I have tried using a trigger but can't understand how to execute it "maxTicket" number of times to insert tickets in the Tickets Table.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Triggers are probably the way to go.

Comment: @dan08 Using Derby DBMS in Netbeans

Comment: maybe that's the wrong way of looking at it. you could put in triggers to catch inserts, and disallow them if the number of ticket records exceeds the preset max.

Comment: @MarcB I don't quite understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
insert into tickets
(fields)
select distinct (values)
from tickets
where event_id = something
and
(select count(*) + 1
 from tickets join event using (event_id)
 where event_id = something)
<=
(select maxTickets
 from event 
 where event_id = something)
```

Comment: Do I make this into a trigger?

Comment: `DECLARE INT COUNTER
 SET COUNTER = EVENTS.MAXTICKETS
CREATE TRIGGER insertTickets 
AFTER INSERT
ON EVENTS
AS 
BEGIN
    
    while COUNTER<=EVENTS.MAXTICKETS
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO TICKETS VALUES (0,EVENTS.EVENTID,NULL,500,NULL)
            SET COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
       END
END`

Comment: That is what I have but I cannot format it into line by line

Comment: The code in this answer is not intended to be a trigger.  It's a general approach, that's database agnostic, which enables you to restrict the number of records that get entered.